# Clarify about service fabric actor. regarding application and services

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

In an fabric application, consider actor based and in that how many maximum actor services can i use... Because I need to create more than 1000 actor classes..Is that ok to have more than 1000 actor classes in one application...?

Thanking you ,
Regards,
Pramod.S

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to have many Actor types. Make sure your cluster has enough resources (nodes) to run the Actor Services. SF will make sure that the services are distributed across the nodes equally.

Maybe you can group Actor Types that serve common functionality together inside separate applications though. This will help make your solution more manageable.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I can find in ms documentation.

"As general guidance, consider the actor pattern to model your problem or scenario if:
Your problem space involves a large number (thousands or more) of small, independent, and isolated units of state and logic.
You want to work with single-threaded objects that do not require significant interaction from external components, including querying state across a set of actors.
Your actor instances won't block callers with unpredictable delays by issuing I/O operations."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction